# What does __isoc99_sscanf() do?

Tags: c, reverse-engineering

**Here's the lines of code in C:**

```
void func_g(undefined4 pmt1)
{
    int amt, elmt1;
    uint elmt3[3];

    amt = __isoc99_sscanf(pmt1, "%d %d", elmt1, &elmt3);
    return;
}
```

What __isoc99_sscanf trying to do?

Comment: Function names beginning with two underscores are reserved for the implementation. That's an internal function of the compiler.

Comment: You should also see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449181/what-does-double-underscore-const-mean-in-c)

Comment: Based on the name, I guess it's the code for the C99-compatible version of `sscanf()`.

Comment: @Barmar FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56444576/asm-isoc99-scanf-after-function-declaration  Could possibly be considered a dupe - I'll let others decide.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'd be tempted to close this as dupe of the one you linked to be honest.

Comment: `int ... elmt1; ... __isoc99_sscanf(pmt1, "%d %d", elmt1, &elmt3);` looks wrong. Passing a `int` where `int *` expected?  `&elmt3` looks dodgy too as it is not an `int*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isoc99_sscanf` (and other related functions) were introduced in 2007 for compliance with the `C99` standard.  As part of the introduction of the C99 support, `"sscanf"` is redirected to `"__isoc99_sscanf"`.*it is compiler specific syntax gcc uses it*.

**This  function  return the number of input items successfully matched
and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the
event of an early matching failure.**

Comment: This is specific to glibc, I believe.  It would be good to state what compiler/library you are talking about.

Comment: i was talking about gcc.